# Devolver los caracteres más comunes de una comparación de 2 cadenas(String) en Php

Tags: php

** Funciones string **
Lo que quiero es obtener el string común más largo luego de comparar 2 string. En el siguiente código obtengo los 2 más comunes es decir, tanto la -oo- como la -eee-. Yo quiero solo la -eee- ya que en este caso es el común más largo.
Logro hacer que elimine la coincidencia de -r- usando la función trim.

```
 $string1 = "carooteee"; 
 $string2 = "Pooreee"; 
 for ($i = 0; $i <strlen($string2); $i++) { 
 if (stripos($string1, $string2[$i])) { 
 $show = trim($string2[$i], "r"); 
 echo $show; 
 } 
 }  
//output: ooeee
//quiero solo: eee por ser el más largo.
```

Answer (score 1):

**Resuelto**

```
<?php
$string1 ="balooneees";
$string2 =" ceeertificadoos";
$car= str_split($string1,1);
$car2= str_split($string2,1);
$val = array_count_values((array_intersect($car, $car2)));
    foreach($val as $key => $value){
    if($value === max($value)){
    echo substr($string1,stripos($string1, $key),max($val));
    }
    //output: eee por ser el más largo string.
    }

?>
```